# Install ssl certificate from azure key vault with Automation Accounts

Tags: azure, ssl, automation, azure-keyvault

i have some issues. 
I have in key vault some SSL certs from LetsEncrypt,and i want to automate installing certificates to VM in azure. I create runbook with some code:

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{# Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         
    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}$certUrl = (Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "MyVault" -Name "letsecrypt-my-cert").Id;
$vm=Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName "MyRS" -Name "MyVm"
$vaultId=(Get-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName "MyVault").ResourceId
$certStore = "MySSL"
$vm = Add-AzureRmVMSecret -VM $vm -SourceVaultId $vaultId -CertificateStore $certStore -CertificateUrl $certURL
Update-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName "MyRS" -VM $vm
```

It install ssl to my VM, but i want to check some parameters of certificate and run this script, for example: if certificate updated run install to vm and if not do nothing. What parameters i must use and how check them. Maybe someone do similar task?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issues with these code modification:

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}
$certUrl = (Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "MyVault" -Name "letsecrypt-MyCert").Id
$vm=Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName "MyRG" -Name "MyVm"
$certUrlOnVM=$vm.osProfile.secrets.vaultCertificates.certificateUrl
$vaultId=(Get-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName "MyVault").ResourceId
$curentDate = Get-Date
$d = $curentDate.day
$m = $curentDate.month
$y = $curentDate.year
$curentDateStr = "$d/$m/$y"
$certStore = "MySSL_"+$curentDateStr
if ($certUrl.equals($certUrlOnVM)){
    "Certificate already installed on VM"
} else {
Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName "MyRG" -Name "MyVm" | Remove-AzureRmVMSecret | Update-AzureRmVM
$vm = Add-AzureRmVMSecret -VM $vm -SourceVaultId $vaultId -CertificateStore $certStore -CertificateUrl $certURL
Update-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName "MyRG" -VM $vm
"Certificate installed on VM successfully"
}
```

I add some variables for get certificate url in key vault and section certificateUrl from OSProfile on vm. I check if cert in keyvault and vm are identical, i do nothing, if not i do remove old section on vm and install new cert.